# how to connect 2 domain controllers on different subnets through a switch

Tags: windows

I have 2 domain controllers (DC's) situated in adjacent buildings. These 2 DC's have the following details

DC1 - Subnet : 192.168.1.X
DC2 - Subnet : 192.168.0.X

DC1 serves 125 clients through DHCP 192.168.1.11 to 192.168.1.200 using switches
DC2 serves 100 clients through DHCP 192.168.0.11 to 192.168.0.200 using switches

I want to connect DC1 and DC2 by connecting one of the switches serving DC1 to one of the switches serving DC2.

My aim is to have users on DC1 access resources on DC2 and vice versa.

Please guide me.

Comment: You will need some kind of router. And a basic networking knowledge.

Comment: Or a switch that is capable of routing (Layer 3 switch)

Answer (score 3):

Even if you were able to route the traffic correctly, you would still need to establish trusts between the two domains for them to cross-authenticate users, which is your stated goal.

Unfortunately, it sounds like your completely our of your league on this one. First, you'll need someone knowledgeable in networking and specifically IP routing, and some router hardware as well. Second, you'll want a skilled AD admin who has experience in establishing cross-forest trusts.